# Can I get the ParameterValue from a ControlParameter (instead of the DefaultValue)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, parameters

I'm having some troubles trying to get a value out of a `ControlParameter` (declared in a `sqlDataSource` in markup).

When debugging, I get this:
[image: Debug of ControlParameter]

As you can see, the DefaultValue is `""` but the `ParameterValue` is `"1" {String}`.  Is it possible to get the `ParameterValue` from code behind?

Additional information:

- I have tried debugging during `inserting`, `inserted`, `updating` and `updated` event handlers.
- The `ControlParameter` is declared in markup as such: `<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hidMetricID" Name="metricID" DefaultValue="" />`
- The datasource correctly inserts/updates the database and gives no error.
- I am using VB.NET on Visual Studio 2010 (although C# answers are also welcome).

Is there anything else I'm missing?  Can I not see the wood through the trees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to get the value from the `SqlDataSource`'s parameters directly, try looking at the event that has been triggered (`inserting`, `inserted`, `selecting`, `selected`, `updating`, `updated`, `deleting` or `deleted`).

Note that the default `Sub`/`void` uses `System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs` (`e`).  This will contain the parameters as they are sent to the SQL server.

Using `e`, we can find `e.Command.Parameters` and in this collection, you can access the values.

For example, assuming the code in the question is being run inside an 'updating' or 'updated' event handler, you could use:
`e.Command.Paramters("metricGroupID").Value` which will return the value that the database will be using in the `Update` command.